# ListViewWebPart not showing "Add new Item" link

Tags: 2010, list-view-web-part, toolbar

The "Add new item" link below the list is not showing.

I use my own site template to create these web parts. Code here:

```
        <ListViewWebPart
        FileName="Default.aspx"
        Title="$Resources:Workspaces,ContactsList_Title;"
        ListName="$Resources:NHO.Arena.SRUWorkspaces,ContactsList_Title;"
        ViewName="$Resources:Workspaces,ContactsList_DefaultView;"
        ZoneID="WebPartZoneLeft"
        ZoneIndex="1"
        ToolbarType="Summary Toolbar"
        AllowMinimize="false"
        AllowClose="false"
        AllowHide="false"
        AllowZoneChange="false"
        AllowConnect="false"
        AllowEdit="true"
        />
```

But the "Summary Toolbar" with the "Add new item" is not showing. Only when I edit the web part, and choose Apply (without changing any settings) then it will show.

I can't ask the users to edit the web parts every time they create a new site, any tips that can help me will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you check after clicking Apply on the web part's panel is it still ListViewWebPart or it is changed to XsltListViewWebPart automatically? I've seen this in SP2010.

Comment: @Naim Thanks, I didn't notice it at first, but it did get changed when I applied it. But why did it now show in listwebpart, but shows on xsltlistwebpart? Another thing I am thinking of, is "Sumary Toolbar" a valid option for ToolbarType property?

Comment: It should be a valid option. The automatic transformation happens no matter which toolbar is selected. You better use XsltListViewWebPart instead of ListViewWebPart.